# How to design a one-to-one relationship that can be either one-to-(parent) or one-to-(child)?

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a site where people can rate/review liquors ("Spirits"). Given that some spirits can vary wildly from bottle-to-bottle, I would like users to have the option to review either the spirit itself, or they can choose to review a *specific bottle* of that spirit.

Consider the tables (SQL Server) below:

```
Spirits
+--------+------------------+
| Column | Type             |
+--------+------------------+
| Id     | uniqueidentifier |
| Name   | nvarchar(255)    |
+--------+------------------+

Bottles
+----------+------------------+
| Column   | Type             |
+----------+------------------+
| Id       | uniqueidentifier |
| SpiritId | uniqueidentifier |
+----------+------------------+

Ratings
+----------+------------------------+
| Column   | Type                   |
+----------+------------------------+
| Id       | uniqueidentifier       |
| SpiritId | uniqueidentifier       |
| BottleId | uniqueidentifier, null |
| Score    | int                    |
+----------+------------------------+
```

Am I approaching the `Ratings` table correctly? If so, how do I enforce that `BottleId` is a child of `SpiritId`?

Or, should I require `SpiritId` **or** `BottleId`, but not both (and is there a way to enforce this requirement in the database?)

I'm sure a question like this has been asked but I'm having enough trouble phrasing it myself, therefore my search attempts didn't yield anything helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I enforce that BottleId is a child of SpiritId

One way to do this is with a composite alternate key (unique constraint) on the `Bottles` table `SpiritId` and `BottleId` columns. The `Ratings` table can then have a foreign key referencing both columns of the `Bottles` table to ensure the spirit and bottle match. Note that a foreign key can reference columns of a unique constraint or unique index, not just the primary key.

Rows with `NULL` foreign key values are not checked for referential integrity so  a rating with a `NULL` BottleId will be permitted as long as the SpiritId is valid, enforced by the foreign key constraint on `SpiritId` alone.

Sample DDL and data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Spirits(
      Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Spirits PRIMARY KEY
    , Name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Bottles(
      Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Bottles PRIMARY KEY
    , SpiritId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_Bottles_Spirits FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Spirits(Id)
    , CONSTRAINT UQ_Bottles_Id_SpiritId UNIQUE (SpiritId, Id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Ratings(
      Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Ratings PRIMARY KEY
    , SpiritId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Spirits(Id)
    , BottleId uniqueidentifier NULL
    , Score int NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT FK_Ratings_Bottles FOREIGN KEY (SpiritId, BottleId) REFERENCES dbo.Bottles(SpiritId, Id)
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Spirits (Id, Name)
    VALUES('8F4A2202-528B-4B7B-9B60-2EFD2F30534A', 'Gin')
INSERT INTO dbo.Spirits (Id, Name)
    VALUES('43C748B9-4876-4D2A-AAF4-30AD8D66BDE7', 'Whiskey')
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Bottles (Id, SpiritId)
    VALUES('78D3E2A8-327C-43C6-A68F-0E74E49E8CC2', '8F4A2202-528B-4B7B-9B60-2EFD2F30534A');
INSERT INTO dbo.Bottles (Id, SpiritId)
    VALUES('826B6FA6-4BC0-4C4D-942B-724D77E26C22', '8F4A2202-528B-4B7B-9B60-2EFD2F30534A');
INSERT INTO dbo.Bottles (Id, SpiritId)
    VALUES('CC4EEC4D-7FBF-4406-BFF8-1A7C66829880', '43C748B9-4876-4D2A-AAF4-30AD8D66BDE7');
INSERT INTO dbo.Bottles (Id, SpiritId)
    VALUES('BACAE7FD-F122-4A6B-8327-5E5E59E298C2', '43C748B9-4876-4D2A-AAF4-30AD8D66BDE7');
GO

--gin rating without specific bottle - allowed
INSERT INTO dbo.Ratings (Id, SpiritId, BottleId, Score)
    VALUES(NEWID(), '8F4A2202-528B-4B7B-9B60-2EFD2F30534A', NULL, 5); 
--gin with gin bottle - allowed
INSERT INTO dbo.Ratings (Id, SpiritId, BottleId, Score)
    VALUES(NEWID(), '8F4A2202-528B-4B7B-9B60-2EFD2F30534A', '826B6FA6-4BC0-4C4D-942B-724D77E26C22', 6); 
--gin rating with whiskey bottle - not allowed
INSERT INTO dbo.Ratings (Id, SpiritId, BottleId, Score)
    VALUES(NEWID(), '8F4A2202-528B-4B7B-9B60-2EFD2F30534A', '43C748B9-4876-4D2A-AAF4-30AD8D66BDE7', 7); 
--whiskey with whiskey bottle - allowed
INSERT INTO dbo.Ratings (Id, SpiritId, BottleId, Score)
    VALUES(NEWID(), '43C748B9-4876-4D2A-AAF4-30AD8D66BDE7', 'CC4EEC4D-7FBF-4406-BFF8-1A7C66829880', 8);
--whiskey with gin bottle - not allowed
INSERT INTO dbo.Ratings (Id, SpiritId, BottleId, Score)
    VALUES(NEWID(), '43C748B9-4876-4D2A-AAF4-30AD8D66BDE7', '78D3E2A8-327C-43C6-A68F-0E74E49E8CC2', 9); 
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Dan! This seems to be exactly what I'm after. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I approaching the Ratings table correctly?

I don't see anything glaringly wrong with your design of it.

> If so, how do I enforce that BottleId is a child of SpiritId?

You already are enforcing that in your `Bottles` table by making it reference a `Spirit` via the non-nullable foreign key field `SpiritId`. You'll want to make sure you actually create a foreign key object to enforce that relationship, in practice.

---

An alternative way you could structure it as well is a separate table for `SpiritRatings` vs `BottleRatings`. You don't have to do this, as your current design seems ok to me at first glance, but you may find this alternative design more beneficial in the future should you add columns to the ratings that only apply to one but not the other.

Comment: thank you for your reply. To clarify, I am enforcing that via foreign key in the Bottles table, but at this point I have to independent foreign keys on the Ratings table. Hypothetically, you could insert a Rating with a SpiritId and a BottleId that aren't related at all, which I'm hoping to avoid. I believe Dan's composite key suggestion accomplishes this.